# Three.js : Image Based Lighting (IBL)

Tags: three.js

I'm searching to add an IBL to my scene and objects. But I can't find anything on the web. There are some examples with an envMap, but the problem is that with the envMap the object looks like chrome...
[image: Sphere with envMap]

I'm trying to have such an effect:
[image: Object with IBL]

I found that you can use IBL (Image Based Lighting), PRT (Precomputed Radiance Transfer) or PBR (Physically Based Rendering). But I'm unable to know how to use such an effect with three.js.

**[EDIT]**

After using the new `MeshStandardMaterial` from the `r74dev` I'm able to have the following result:
(before)
[image: Whithout MeshStandardMaterial]
(after)
[image: With MeshStandardMaterial]

But I can't use `MeshStandardMaterial` and `envMap` with textures. Either the texture or the `MeshStandardMaterial` dooesn't work.

Comment: Try `MeshStandardMaterial` in the dev branch r.74dev. Environment maps for that material are treated as an IBL.

Comment: And is it possible to use it with dae files using textures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to WestLangley I'm using `MeshStandardMaterial`:

```
var objectGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 100, 100 );  
material  = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({envMap : textureSkydome});
```

(r74dev)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use lightmaps. You can use them with `THREE.MeshPhongMterial` by setting `material.lightmap = someLightmapTexture`. Important - you need a second set of UVs in your geometry in order to use lightmaps.

have a look at this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_lightmap).