# Three.js : Image Based Lighting

Tags: three.js

Since I still can't comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695033/three-js-image-based-lighting-ibl), I'll make a new question.

Previous iterations of r74dev allowed you to have an environment map and fake some sort of IBL, allowing you to have an unlit scene looking nice (in both examples, a single white directional light is at the left, just for the demo, the right part is how it looks unlit).
[image: The right part is still redish]

This was fine for the little project I was doing, but now, lightning is taken into account, relegating the environment map to "just" that.
[image]

Is it possible to replicate the functionality so that it works with the final r74 release?

The r74dev I use have some quirks such as having to set roughness to -0.999 so the surface is fully smooth, and I understand the behaviour in general wasn't the most correct one.

**EDIT:** New pics and JSFiddle of the pics, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hashjedu/).

Change the script tags in the HTML to switch between versions:

```
<!-- Current development three.js -->
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.js"></script>

<!-- Three.js from the 8th of november -->
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/becea58835be00da49fae6695098769300689766/build/three.js"></script>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show some code so we know what you are doing?

Comment: Ok, I see you explicitly disabled the code in this [commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/534877d3040759c5683e7c4ff62701a7b8d24385).
Re-enabling it seems to work nicely. I'll add this an answer some time in the future if there is no better answer, other than fix the "todo" in the shader. Which I would love to if it wasn't that I only feel capable of adding a switch to the material.